# Meteor mobile app. Custom site authentication and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: authentication, meteor, cors

I need to develop a mobile app and allow it to authenticate via some corporate site via SOAP. I tried to send some GET/POST requests to different sites (from client code) and am always observing the same error, like

```
I20150602-18:54:17.186(3) (android:http://meteor.local/:0) XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. Origin http://meteor.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I tried to create `mobile-config.js` file with the following content

```
App.accessRule("*");
```

but this didn't help.

I don't know why this setting doesn't do the trick and now I'm not sure should I authenticate from client or server code?

I'm using Meteor 1.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue with Meteor cordova apps.

According to the response on https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4132 you can use the browser policy package to solve this issue:

```
meteor add browser-policy
```

Add this bit of code in:

Server side code:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("http://meteor.local");
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread and some others. I tried this method and it hasn't helped.

Comment: @gumkins You might want to mention this on that thread as I have also voiced.

Comment: I mentioned it in another thread https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3469#issuecomment-108005269 ;-)